# ctypes loading a c shared library that has dependencies

Tags: python, linux, ctypes

On Linux, I have a c shared library that depends on other libs. LD_LIBRARY_PATH is properly set to allow the linker to load all the libraries. When I do:

```
libgidcwf    = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libidcwf_path)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "libwfm_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    libgidcwf    = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libidcwf_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: path-to-my-lib/libwav.so: undefined symbol: ODBCGeneralQuery
```

It seems that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has no effect here.
Is there a way to have these dependency library "loadable"?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What OS are you on?  See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html -- it's `SHLIB_PATH` in HpUx, `LIBPATH` in Aix, `DYLD_lotsofthings` on Mac... semantics also differ subtly. Even if Linux, pls clarify version and tag your Q appropriately, thanks!

Comment: I am on Linux so I use LD_LIBRARY_PATH but it doesn't seem to be used by ctypes

Answer (score 18):

It would seem that libwav.so does not declare it's dependency on the library defining ODBCGeneralQuery. Try running `ldd path-to-my-lib/libwav.so` and see if there's something missing. If this is a shared library that you are building you should add `-llibname` to the linking command (the one that is something like `gcc -shared -o libwav.so a.o b.o c.o`) for each library that the library's code uses. Any other libraries referenced by the original shared library in this way should automatically be loaded as well.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if you would elaborate on "something missing". I run ldd on my .so - but what am I supposed to see?

Comment: I guess my meaning is unclear. I meant that ldd will show the libraries that libwav.so references and that should be inspected to see if there is a library that should be listed but is not.

Comment: Thank you so much for actually clarifying this four-year old answer. I find the output from `ldd` a bit confusing, but your answer helps clarifying it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You should use [RTLD_GLOBAL](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen).  I have a mixed platform system, so my code looks something like this:

```
import numpy, ctypes
try:
  if "Linux" in esmfos:
    _ESMF = ctypes.CDLL(libsdir+'/libesmf.so', mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
  else:
    _ESMF = numpy.ctypeslib.load_library('libesmf', libsdir)
except:
  traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
  sys.exit(ESMP_ERROR_SHAREDLIB)
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem.
Two things were required in order to solve it:

1. use the `RTLD_GLOBAL` as other users said
2. You need to load every library that is used by your library. So if `ODBCGeneralQuery` is defined in lets say `libIDCodbc`, you need first run this line:

`ctypes.CDLL("libIDCodbc.so", mode = ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)`

Comment: what exactly does `RTLD_GLOBAL` do? Does it say "if you load a bunch of .so files, put all the symbols into one giant namespace"?

Comment: @Tommy I am late for the party, but according to https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.PyDLL and then https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/manpages-dev/dlopen.3.en.html#RTLD_GLOBAL , the `RTLD_GLOBAL` mode means making the symbols available for subsequently loaded shared objects

Answer (score 8):

I found I had to use `RTLD_LAZY` due to an undefined symbol that was not linked because it was not being used. Since there is no `ctypes.RTLD_LAZY` in my ctypes, I had to use:

```
ctypes.CDLL(libidcwf_path, mode=1)
```

I found this mode by inspecting `/usr/include/bits/dlfcn.h` which is probably not standard. Hat tip to this 2006 [thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/ctypes/mailman/message/8470422/) on the ctypes mailing list.

Comment: In Python 3 use `from posix import RTLD_LAZY` or `os.RTLD_LAZY` as methioned by Rookie in another answer. I still haven't found this constant in Python 2.

Answer (score 6):

When you compile the shared object, be sure to put all the `-lsomething` at the end of the string command. For me it solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Walter Nissen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47945351/815196) above, you can modify the code to be:

```
import os
ctypes.CDLL(libidcwf_path, mode=os.RTLD_LAZY)
```