# Using ctypes to wrap compiled library with dependancies

Tags: python, c, linux, ctypes

I'm trying to use a library called pvcam (Photometrics Virtual Camera Access Method) with ctypes. This proprietary library is distributed as a compiled shared object (.so file) with a Software User Manual and works fine for C development.
I would like to wrap this library with ctypes so I can use python instead of C.
I've tried

```
ctypes.CDLL('libpvcam.so.2.7.4.2',mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
```

but then python complains about a dependancy.

```
OSError: /usr/lib/libpvcam.so.2.7.4.2: undefined symbol: raw1394_new_handle
```

(I do have libraw1394 installed) according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327344/ctypes-loading-a-c-shared-library-that-has-dependencies) the library might have to be recompiled properly with correct flags. Being a proprietary pre-compiled object this is not possible.
How can I load this .so to ctypes in python?

Comment: It is unlikely that you will be wrap a library for which you do not have source code, sorry (at least not in a trivial way, and it will most likely break the licencing agreement). Best way to go would be to contact the supplier.

Comment: When you link that lib with a C program, do you have some errors? What if you compile with the -fPIC option ? From memory: if this is only a question of path, you might try to investigate LD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_PRELOAD. Have you tried to run `ldd` on your library to see dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading the required library beforehand:

```
ctypes.CDLL('libraw1394.so.X.Y', mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
ctypes.CDLL('libpvcam.so.2.7.4.2', mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
```